# bash ./ command stopped working with pyvenv?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I'm using python 3 and have many virtual envs using pyvenv on mac osx 10.9.3. In all of them the command ./ runs my python code. In one of my envs the command has stopped working and I can not find anything about how to get it to begin working again.

EDIT: I get permission denied when typing out the whole file instead of tab (i.e. ./manage.py), and when I add sudo it works, but all the other venvs don't require sudo.

I'm searching through [pyvenv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and searching through various bash links but can't get it to restore or know where that shortcut comes from.

When I type python [file] everything works as expected, but I want to restore the ./[file] I know it's going to be something easy but for some reason I can't figure out what to search to get the relevant solution.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: normally I tab and it finds the file. I typed out the whole ./manage.py and it says permission denied. I tried with sudo it works correctly, however all my other venvs don't require sudo

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chmod a+x manage.py` or `sudo chown my_user:my_group manage.py` ?

Comment: no. Are those things that would restore the functionality to use ./ to run py files without sudo or onetime solutions?

Comment: you should try the first one and see what happens. It makes the file executable.

Comment: did you create one of the files or projects using sudo?

Comment: @Jivan, if it was not executable you would get something like `command not found` using sudo

Comment: what does `ls -l manage.py` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `True` but it might be that only su has the rights to execute the file

Comment: that outputs -rw-rw-r--  1 awwester  staff  256 Dec 19 17:38 manage.py

Comment: ok so it is not executable, there is no way it ran with sudo either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `./[tab]` and the file you're expecting doesn't come in linux shell, chances are you need to make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x manage.py
```

Or you don't have sufficient permissions to access the file:

```
sudo chown user:group manage.py
```

(Be careful with the last one because it may lead to unexpected behaviour)

Comment: thanks, sudo chmod a+x manage.py did work. Thanks for explaining

Comment: You should not need sudo if you have permissions you just need `chmod +x manage.py`